# (Python): Else not executing in while loop?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

My code loops like this:

```
filtered = [] #creates another empty list for the user input letters

substring1 = input("Please enter the first letter you know: ").lower()
substring2 = input("Please enter the second letter you know - (If you don't have a second, just hit enter): ").lower()
substring3 = input("Please enter the third letter you know - (If you don't have a third, just hit enter): ").lower()
substring4 = input("Please enter the fourth letter you know - (If you don't have a fourth, just hit enter): ").lower()
substring5 = input("Please enter the fifth letter you know - (If you don't have a fifth, just hit enter): ").lower()

# adds up the length of characters from each input of the 5 user input lines
length_of_all = len(substring1) + len(substring2) + len(substring3) + len(substring4) + len(substring5)

def while_do_stuffs():
    while length_of_all <= 5: # while loop to check if length of all is 5 or less
        break
    else:
        print("Too many characters! Total of all 5 lines must be less than or equal to 5!")

for string in five_letter_words:
# this next line is basically saying look for all strings in the latter 5 (or less) user inputs, and search them against the 5 letter word list
    if substring1 in string and substring2 in string and substring3 in string and substring4 in string and substring5 in string:
        filtered.append(string) # modify the word list to *only* include words that contain the matching letters from the (up to) 5 inputs.
print(filtered) #print final output of 5 letter words matching the letters provided in the user input
```

I'm basically trying to make it execute the last 5 lines of code if the while statement is true, otherwise print the message after else and try again.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something really simple but I'm too much of a beginner here to figure it out.

Comment: `else` only runs if the while loop stops due to the condition returning `False`. The `break` here bypasses checking the condition, meaning the `else` block is skipped.

Comment: This isn't how functions work at all... read up on the basics [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: Your code does not call the function `while_do_stuffs()`. So it’s not the `else` that isn't executing. The whole function isn't executing, because it never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You re using while loop and function in wrong way.
Add your first input functions inside the `while` loop, then check the length of the string with `if else`. If the condition is True, `break` from the loop and execute the rest of the code. Else go back to retry with `continue`. With the given info I don't see any need to use a function.

```
filtered = [] #creates another empty list for the user input letters


while True:
    substring1 = input("Please enter the first letter you know: ").lower()
    substring2 = input("Please enter the second letter you know - (If you don't have a second, just hit enter): ").lower()
    substring3 = input("Please enter the third letter you know - (If you don't have a third, just hit enter): ").lower()
    substring4 = input("Please enter the fourth letter you know - (If you don't have a fourth, just hit enter): ").lower()
    substring5 = input("Please enter the fifth letter you know - (If you don't have a fifth, just hit enter): ").lower()

    # adds up the length of characters from each input of the 5 user input lines
    length_of_all = len(substring1) + len(substring2) + len(substring3) + len(substring4) + len(substring5)

    if length_of_all<= 5: # while loop to check if length of all is 5 or less
        break
    else:
        print("Too many characters! Total of all 5 lines must be less than or equal to 5!")
        continue

five_letter_words= "hello"

for string in five_letter_words:
# this next line is basically saying look for all strings in the latter 5 (or less) user inputs, and search them against the 5 letter word list
    if substring1 in string and substring2 in string and substring3 in string and substring4 in string and substring5 in string:
        filtered.append(string) # modify the word list to *only* include words that contain the matching letters from the (up to) 5 inputs.
print(filtered) #print final output of 5 letter words matching the letters provided in the user input
```

Also you can make a single string by concatenating substrings and check the lenght at once, instead of adding lenght of each substring individually.

```
length_of_all = len(substring1 +substring2 +substring3 +substring4 +substring5)
```